# I want to move to another view controller without using navigation controller, segue,storyboard and animation. Anyone can help me?

Tags: swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I want to move to another view controller without using navigation controller, segue, storyboard and animation

Answer (score -1):

You can use `presentViewController` like this

```
let controller =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_ID")
self.presentViewController(controller!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans but I also dont want to use storyboard just to make our own custom methods to move to another view controller